# After switching google cloud projects my python cannot find my new google project's storage bucket?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-storage

I created a new project and even though all the IAM permissions are set and local login credentials are correct, I cannot connect to my bucket using python's google storage API (Windows)

I updated the gcloud authentication and it shows I am using the correct login, and even retried uninstalling and reinstalling Google Cloud SDK, but my python can't seem to connect?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with hidden old credentials not being updated in the AppData/Roaming/gcloud. After deleting this folder, uninstalling and reinstalling Google Cloud SDK, it was able to work.

Answer (score 0):

The Application Default Credentials (ADC) are still set.

they can be revoked and new ones be set

```
gcloud auth application-default revoke
gcloud auth application-default login
```

More info here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc